# OpenLayers adding Polygon from coordinates

Tags: android, openlayers

I have a set of coordinates and need to put a polygon on the map. This is my code, but it's currently not working (the polygon just doesn't appear)

```
var polygon = JSInterface.getPolygonValue();
var coordinates = [];
for (var i in polygon) {
    var coord = polygon[i];
    var point = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point(coord.getLongitude(), coord.getLatitude());
    coordinates.push(point);
}
// style definition
var siteStyle = {

};

var linearRing = new OpenLayers.Geometry.LinearRing(coordinates);
var geometry = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon([linearRing]);
var polygonFeature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(geometry, null, siteStyle);
var vector = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vector layer");
vector.addFeatures([polygonFeature]);
map.addLayer(vector);
```

"polygon" is an

```
ArrayList<Coordinate> polygon = new ArrayList<Coordinate>();
```

and Coordinate class:

```
public class Coordinate {
    double longitude;
    double latitude;

    public double getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
     this.latitude = latitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. It is possible it is related to coordinate system/projection.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the looping for...in? Because the code within is not being executed.

Comment: It is hard to know without seeing what var polygon = JSInterface.getPolygonValue(); returns